# How can I add a list of offset checkboxes to an NSScrollView?

Tags: swift, macos

I have an `NSScrollView` that I am trying to populate with check boxes (`NSButton` / `NSToggleButton`). The number of checkboxes I add should be equal to a number of items in an array. This part is working.

The following code successfully adds the checkboxes to the scroll view, but they are all on top of each other. I am trying to add them, but offset from each other in a "list view" manner such as a tableview on iOS. Here's my code:

```
for calendar in self.allCalendars {
     self.allCalendars.append(calendar as EKCalendar)        
     let checkbox = NSButton.init(checkboxWithTitle: calendar.title, target: self, action: #selector(self.checkboxDidChange))
     checkbox.setButtonType(NSToggleButton)
     self.checkboxArray.append(checkbox as NSButton)
     self.addSubview(checkbox)       
}
```

And here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at `NSTableView`?

Comment: No I haven't. It looks much better suited to achieve what I'm trying to do here. This is my first osx app and didn't realize this was available. Obviously getting what I currently have implemented would be my first choice, but `NSTableView` looks like a good option.

Comment: Have you done iOS programming before? Each of the buttons is getting a frame with top-left at 0,0 so they're all on top of each other. You need to adjust the frame as you add them. You could also check out `NSStackView` if you don't want to do frame math.

Comment: Sorry "Have you done iOS programming before?" sounds condescending. I was just trying to gauge your general familiarity with the topic.

Comment: Why don't you use NButton.init(frame: xxx)?

Comment: Done a fair amount of iOS but usually with storyboards + `UITableView`'s. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that you could implement, it would change how you do your loop so that you have an index of each iteration, but it can help you calculate some sort of vertical spacing:

```
for i in 0 ..< allCalendars.count {

    let margin: CGFloat = 5.0   // Or whatever you want the padding on the left to be

    let vertSpacing: CGFloat = 10.0    // However much separation you want in between boxes

    self.allCalendars.append(allCalendars[i] as EKCalendar)
    let checkbox = NSButton.init(checkboxWithTitle: allCalendars[i].title, target: self, action: #selector(self.checkboxDidChange))
    checkbox.setButtonType(NSToggleButton)

    // Now you can set the frame of the checkbox within it's superview's coordinate system
    // This calculates it based on the bounds.height, if you want to use a custom height, substitute that.
    checkbox.frame = CGRect(x: margin, y: vertSpacing + (vertSpacing + checkbox.bounds.height)*CGFloat(i), width: checkbox.bounds.width, height: checkbox.bounds.height)

    self.checkboxArray.append(checkbox as NSButton)
    self.addSubview(checkbox)

}
```

Basically what that y-value `vertSpacing + (vertSpacing + checkbox.bounds.height)*CGFloat(i)` does is it starts the very first checkbox off with a y-pos of whatever you set your vertical spacing value to be, and then for every checkbox after, it will set it one vertical space value below the previous checkbox. This solution will assume that each checkbox is of the same height. You can set a custom height if you don't want to use the `bounds.height` value.

Comment: Worked! Thank you. I just needed to add `let calendar = self.allCalendars[i]` inside the loop so I could get `calendar.title`

Comment: Ohh right! Sorry I just coded that white-board style. I'll edit my answer for future people. Glad it works for you